# 302 Moved when open page using the function fsockopen()

Tags: php, fsockopen

I try to open a page using the function `fsockopen()`, but I get the following output: "HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily". How can I get past this?

Comment: Could it be that the page you are opening actually is moved? What happens if you open the url manually?

Comment: You need to read more lines of the header to see the Location: header which says where it actually went to :)

Comment: Also, to add to @Jensd: Note that things like missing slashes in URLs are handled automatically by webbrowsers who just quietly follow the redirect.

Comment: You could use `cURL` which is more powerful.

Answer (score 0):

Many web applications, .htaccess setups and domain setups utilize subsequent redirects to get you to the intended resource. `fsockopen()` does not follow those redirects automatically and you will need to handle them by yourself. Just as @hegemon has mentioned, you will need the Location: header of the response to figure out the next step. However, there might be multiple subsequent redirects involved thus you will either have to implement your own custom-made solution of following redirects recursively or, as @str suggested, you can switch to some more powerful and well-tested solutions like using the `cURL` library.

Comment: no; the 302 responses are the valid way of handling particular scenarios and the HTTP standard leaves it up to the client (in your case PHP interpreter) if redirects are supposed to be followed; your best solution in this situation is using cURL